# Can't expand nodes in TreeView (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, treeview

I'm filling `TreeView` programmatically (in different thread if it matters).

I want the first level of nodes to be expanded when `TreeView` loads to window. I've tried almost everywhere (in worker thread, in main thread, in event handlers of `Form.Load`, `Form.Shown` etc.), but `TreeView` is still collapsed.

What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

```
treeView.UpdateTree((object tree) => {
    treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(text);
});

public static void UpdateTree(this Control ctrl, Action<object> code) {
    if (ctrl.InvokeRequired) {
        ctrl.BeginInvoke(code, (TreeView)ctrl);
    }
    else {
        code.Invoke((TreeView)ctrl);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
private void btnFillTree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ......
    treeDirectoryContents.Nodes.Add("GeneralFolder");
    ......
    //there I create Thread() that fills treeDirectoryContents
    ......
    treeDirectoryContents.ExpandAll();
}
```

Comment: Not showing your code.....

Comment: @Steve lol what do you want to see? how I write `treeView.Nodes.ExpandAll()` or what ??

Comment: Andrew, seeking help for a "why isn't this code working?" should include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. (It is one of the closing reasons list). I sympathize with you but without seeing the code that fill the treeview and the code that tries to expand, it is a bit difficult to help.

Comment: @Steve ok, don't help if you can't) Can you tell me what events are raised after click event ? I'll try to access tree there...

Comment: @Andrew please revisit the [help] as you don't seem to understand yet that this site is not to help you but also to help future visitors of your question. To reach that goal we require questions and answers to have a certain quality level and comments are used to point that out to you. There is no need to respond in a manner that might be interpreted as rude to some users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far I know (.NET 3.5) you cannot acces GUI elements from different thread (you can prepare some data but must access `TreeView.Nodes` from main thread only - use `Control.BeginInvoke` for that ... you can as well check `Control.InvokeRequired`).

After filling all the nodes you can just do

```
foreach (TreeNode node in treeView) node.Expand()
```

**EDIT after UPDATE2:**

1. Nodes can only be expanded when they have children.
2. Controls can only be accessed from main thread (check `Control.InvokeRequired`)
3. BeginInvoke() is asynchronous (does not wait) while `Invoke()` is synchronous (like BeginInvoke + EndInvoke)
4. Never call `Thread.Join()` from main thread (use `BackgroundWorker.IsBusy` or mimic that by some state variable e.g. `bool done = false; thread.Start(); while(!done) Application.DoEvents()`

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.isbusy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
// Start the download operation in the background. 
this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

// Disable the button for the duration of the download. 
this.downloadButton.Enabled = false;

// Once you have started the background thread you  
// can exit the handler and the application will  
// wait until the RunWorkerCompleted event is raised. 

// Or if you want to do something else in the main thread, 
// such as update a progress bar, you can do so in a loop  
// while checking IsBusy to see if the background task is 
// still running. 

while (this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
{
    progressBar1.Increment(1);
    // Keep UI messages moving, so the form remains  
    // responsive during the asynchronous operation.
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

**EDIT - How I thing it should be done (using Threads)**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyForm : Form {
    public static void Main() {
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }

    TreeView tree = new TreeView() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    MyForm() {
        Controls.Add(tree);
        tree.Nodes.Add("Loading...");
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        new Thread(Fill).Start();
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
    void Create(string text) {
        if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(new Action<string>(this.Create), text);
        else tree.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(text);
    }
    void Finish() {
        if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(new Action(this.Finish));
        else {
            tree.Nodes[0].Text = "The Nodes";
            tree.ExpandAll();
        }
    }
    void Fill() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Create("Node #" + i.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to do it in main thread after fillin tree and closing worker thread... but no effect

Comment: Maybe you should include minimal compilable code. Another guess: try doing it from button.Click event (I am not sure, but I sometimes had problems with controls in initialization state where the handle was not yet created - you can overcome this by calling `Control.CreateHandle()`)

EDIT: Did you rewrite the code not to access TreeView while its InvokeRequired returns true?

Comment: In click event I run worker thread. In this thread I fill TreeView. Then i `Join()` this thread, then I write `myTreeView.ExpandAll()` (in the same click even). No effect

Comment: As I already said: You CANNOT access Controls from BackgroundThread! Try checking TreeView.InvokeRequired before you access TreeView.Nodes. ...in Debug Mode it should throw exception.

Comment: ok, after update: where do you create the first node (the one you want expanded)? ....did you try calling `treeView.Nodes[0].Expand()` after that `Add()`? ....you need at least one child to Expand the node

Comment: I think that you are not doing it in correct order. Calling Join() does not mean that you have finished the job - use `Invoke()` instead of `BeginInvoke()` (second is asynchronous - does not wait, just pushes the message on the loop, first is synchronous - same as calling `BeginInvoke()` + `EndInvoke()`).

Comment: application freezes when I call `Invoke()` instead of `BeginInvoke()`

Comment: That would probably be caused by the `Join()` - nobody is pumping messages (`Application.DoEvents()`). The whole idea is bad, you should wait for the BackroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted (or you can do 'while(worker.IsBusy) Application.DoEvents();` see MSDN Example for `IsBusy`

Comment: my task is to write application only using Thread() class, so I can't use BackgroundWorker

Comment: Ahh, allright, mimic that - use boolean variable e.g. done = false, Thread.Start(), while(!done) Application.DoEvents(); thread.Join(); tree.ExpandAll();

Comment: when and where should I assign this flag to `true` ? sorry, I'm very new to threads...

Comment: at the end of the background method.

Comment: Read the comments again. Read my 4 points again. Now you are doing in both threads what you need to do (start background, sync with main using Invoke(), wait in main while keeping UI in shape by calling Application.DoEvents()).

Comment: @firga interesting thing... About ~1/4 of clicks handled - I get tree collapsed... 3 of 4 I get what it expanded

Comment: @firga no, even worse - 50/50 of clicks handled return either expanded or collapsed tree...

Comment: I cannot track your code. The answer was accepted. If you need something, ask and include FULL CODE (minimal compilable that can reproduce the problem).

Comment: if you don't mind please check my new question, where I tried to explain this problem more detailed and posted some code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980569/how-to-ensure-that-async-method-finished-work

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this. I did not knew that I can't expand if the node does not have child node. Silly me. Of course I can't expand if there is nothing inside.. Anyway thank you a lot!