# How to ensure that async method finished work?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, treeview

I'm very new to threads, so my thoughts and questions might be a bit silly :)

I fill `WinForm` control with data from another thread, so I have to call `Invoke()` when I'm trying to access control.

If I understand correctly, `treeView.BeginInvoke(/*some Action()*/)` makes this `Action<>()` run in main thread. But I "fire and forget" this `BeginInvoke()`, so I can't know when the work is actually done. And even when worker thread closes and execution returns to main thread, I can't be sure that all `BeginInvoke()` methods have finished execution.

That's why even after returning to main thread I can't manage with `Control` to which I fired `BeginInvoke()`.

**The actual problem** is `TreeView.ExpandAll()` doesn't work.

Take a look at the code snippet below.

```
private void btnGetTree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var treeViewWriter = new Thread(() => UpdateTreeView(new AddXmlNodeArgs(di, null), treeDirectoryContents));
    treeViewWriter.Start();
    treeViewWriter.Join();
    treeDirectoryContents.ExpandAll();
}

// method runs on a worker thread
public static void UpdateTreeView(AddXmlNodeArgs args, TreeView treeView) {
    // I will miss details... Here is the code that I run for every new TreeNode:
    treeView.UpdateTree((TreeView tree) => {
        tree.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(newTreeNode); // treeView.Nodes[0]...
    });
}

// Extension method for TreeView
public static void UpdateTree(this TreeView tree, Action<TreeView> code) {
    if (tree.InvokeRequired)
        tree.BeginInvoke(code, tree);
    else
        code.Invoke(tree);
}
```

I fire `tree.BeginInvoke()` but I don't call `EndInvoke()` anywhere. So I guess when in `btnGetTree_Click` execution reaches to `treeDirectoryContents.ExpandAll()` - not all `Invoke()` methods have finished their work. Thats why `.ExpandAll() doesn't work`.

Correct me if I'm wrong, and please give an advice how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you create a thread and then wait it to finish in `btnGetTree_Click` ? No need for a thread in this usage

Comment: @L.B I've posted only the code you need to see to understand my problem. I have multiple threads in `btnGetTree_Click` which work like "producer/multiple consumers"

Comment: All this originally started here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975972/cant-expand-nodes-in-treeview-winforms/24976017?noredirect=1#comment38833518_24976017

Comment: @jamesbong Seems like it is good time to learn TPL library and async/await.  Start maultiple *Task*s then `await Task.WhenAll(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely wrong:

```
treeViewWriter.Start();
treeViewWriter.Join();
```

**Never call Thread.Join from Main Thread!** because that `Join` freezes the application and all those `BeginInvoke`/`Invoke` never gets fully executed because the message is not handled.

This is how `BeginInvoke()` actually works:

1. It sends some WM_USER (or the like) on message loop.
2. Main thread pops this message in `Application.DoEvents()` (or the like which is always called in `Application.Run()`)
3. Main thread executes the delegate passed to `BeginInvoke()`
4. Main thread signals end of execution (by `WaitHandle` in `IAsyncResult`)
5. `EndInvoke()` waits for such signal (or if `IAsyncResult` from `BeginInvoke` is never stored, it gets garbage-collected)

So again: you eiter write it purely event-driven or do something like this:

```
private bool done = false;
void click(object, EventArgs) {
    thread.Start();
    while(!done) Application.DoEvents();
    tree.ExpandAll();
}
```

**ADDON:**
Eihter use `Invoke()` (synchronized) and the above loop with `Application.DoEvents()`
or use BeginInvoke() and call your ExpandAll the same way (through BeginInvoke() from the thread)

**ADDON2:**

```
private bool done;
void click(object,EventArgs) {
    done = false; // init state
    new Thread(work).Start(); // start backgound work
    while(!done) Application.DoEvents(); // wait until done
    finish(); } // finish the job in main thread
void work() {
    Thread.Sleep(100); // do your work
    done = true; } // signal done
void finish() {
    whatever(); } // called on main thread

void click2(object,EventArgs) {
    new Thread(work2).Start(); } // just start the hread
void work2() {
    Thread.Sleep(100); // do your work
    BeginInvoke(new Action(finish)); } // execute finish() on main thread
```

Comment: yesterday I've read a great post about "Why you shouldn't use `Application.DoEvents()`". So I'm trying to find the other way to solve my problem

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` is bad if you do heavy work in main thread and use this to get at least some responsiveness. It is absolutely fine if you do the heavy work in other thread and just wait for it to finish in such while(!done) Application.DoEvents() loop. ...but: there usually is a pure-events way :)

Comment: At the end of background work. new Thread(DoWork).Start() void DoWork() { doit(); done = true; } ....better way is to call somehing like BeginInvoke(Finish) and do what you want to do there (after the loop)

Comment: if I do like you advice, 50/50 I get either collapsed or expanded tree

Comment: and the code? you are probably doing something wrong, so rather again: Either use while(!done) ... and Invoke ONLY! (no BeginInvoke) **OR** ALWAYS BeginInvoke even for the last finish call. Which one did you choose? ....look at my original answer and the last example (tested!) http://stackoverflow.com/a/24976017/1722660

Comment: I used `bool Done` with `BeginInvoke()` calls... If I write `Invoke()` instead of `BeginInvoke()` - program freezes :(( I've also tried to `BeginInvoke()` for the last finish call, but when I write just `BeginInvoke` (like you in your example) compiler says "the name BeginInvoke() doesn't exist in current context"

Comment: this is useless. again and again and again. I'm done unless you post FULL CODE somewhere. This is like throwing peas against the wall, sorry.

Comment: can you leave me your email or skype ? I can't post whole code there for two reasons: 1) I am not allowed to 2) it is too large

Comment: create new minimalistic project (like i did for you there) and reproduce the problem. learn how to report problems (you have been told that by the first person commenting your very first question). I can fix your code but why? You'd learn nothing this way. Understand the problem first, you have all info here (you said your app freezed, I said never use Thread.Join() in main thread - I am 100% sure you did that).

Comment: my skype: level-fires

Comment: @firga yes, a minute ago I realized by myself that `.Join()` made my app freeze :) Now it works fine. Now can you answer one more last question? and then I'll like all your posts for huge help that you made for me :) **Question:** does it make difference for application performance when I call 15 times in a loop `Invoke()` or when I 15 times fire and forget `BeginInvoke()` ?

Comment: BeginInvoke() is better and don't wory, framework programmers were smart and use a queue (push all consecutive BeginInvoke to the queue until main thread pops the messages and executes all queued deleagets).

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Action` which `Invoke`s the delegate, then `BeginInvoke` that action. 
This way you will have a callback which you can move the `ExpandAll` into:

```
if (tree.InvokeRequired)
        new Action(() => { tree.Invoke(code, tree); }).BeginInvoke((ar) => {
            treeDirectoryContents.ExpandAll();
        }, null);
else
    code.Invoke(tree);
```

Note that I replaced your original `BeginInvoke` with a simple `Invoke`.

UPDATE: As firda mentioned correctly, because the main thread is blocked inside the `Join` method waiting for the other thread to exit, executing `Invoke` on the controls will lead to a deadlock. So now that your `ExpandAll` is moved to the callback, you should remove the `Join` and everything will be fine.

Comment: Invoke() + Thread.Join() = DEADLOCK ;) (background thread waiting in Invoke(), main thread locked in Thread.Join() not pumping messages)

Comment: You are totally right. I think there is no need for that `Join` anymore.